# How can have variable data be from a url in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, url, chart.js

I am using chart.js to make a chart, but the docs show the data integrated into the html. I want to get the data from an externel source, such as localhost:80/data. How can i get the var ***barChartData*** to be data from a url?

```
var barChartData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [1,2,3]
            }, {
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [4,5,6]
            }]

        };
```

The url would return this

```
{
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [1,2,3]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
            borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [4,5,6]
        }]

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `fetch()` the data from the url and then pass that through to the chart:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:80/data') // Get the data from the url
    .then(response => response.json()) // Parse the response into json
    .then(data => {
        // The json from the url, use it to create the chart
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // Catch errors
        console.log(e);
    });
```

If you for example have a function called `createChart()`, you can pass the data like this:

```
// Replace the console.log(data) in the then() with the function
.then(createChart)

function createChart(data) {
   // Create chart here with json data
}
```

Comment: It shows:  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 5 of the JSON data

Comment: What does the JSON data look like exactly? Youre example isnt valid JSON

Comment: I fixed it by replacing single quotes with double quotes and putting quotes everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Fetch

```
 var barChartData = fetch('localhost:80/data')
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(err){
    //deal with error
    }
    
    //deal with response you can render it with a for loop
```